# Can the Lowepro Utility 100aw clip onto an ordinary belt?

Tags: camera-bag, lowepro

Does anyone have any experience with this bag. Can you clip the bag to an ordinary trouser belt, or do you have to buy the Lowepro belt system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have that one. It can be put onto a normal pants belt without taking the belt off. The loop on the back of Lowepro S&F items are narrow so works nicely even on a curved belt: it doesn't force the belt to flatten behind it.

Check out the larger StuffIt from ThinkTank. I like it better, but this one is larger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can attach it to any belt.

Take a look at the product page here:

http://store.lowepro.com/s-f-utility-bag-100-aw

in particular the product images, and the one that shows the velcro strap at the rear of the pouch.

I don't have this pouch in particular, but I have another of the Lowepro S&F series pouches.